# Prestashop 1.7.6.5 not taking into account php module modifications

Tags: caching, prestashop

I've been modifying a module and for some reason prestashop does not take into consideration the code modifications in module.php.

I've made modifications a while back and I need to modify it again due to an update that raises an error, the problem is that I get the error even if I remove said line.

I get this type of error: `PHP message: PHP Notice: Undefined index: ordersorderFilter!active in /modules/module/module.php on line 104`
I've commented first than removed that line but I still get the error.
It seems like there is a cache somewhere that I can't find, I've deactivated all possible cache in prestashop, activated debug mode, deleted the dev and prod folders in /var/cache/ but I still get the error.
I've used grep on the server to try to find that line, and when I delete it from the file I can not find it anywhere else on the server (but can find it if I add it).

Anybody has any idea?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prestashop does not perform any kind of caching on the modules PHP files so the problem lies elsewhere or at "lower level" (webserver / proxy ie.).

So check your environment for server-side caching, proxies or PHP accelerators such as opCache that may not serve changes from the source server.

Also try renaming or deleting the offending file altogether and see if the error changes, if not you might simply be looking at the wrong file :)

Comment: Thanks, I was writing to say that the server was configured with opcache from our hosting provider, I asked them to deactivate it and everything worked.